# Develop React Module without compiling the entire project

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm fairly new to React development and one of my projects is getting pretty large. I was wondering if there was any way to develop modules without the need of compiling and running the rest of the project. I know there is unit testing and jest but I'm struggling in how to develop UI on a module w/o compiling the entire project. The project in question is built on ReactJS, Redux, and Firebase.

Comment: storybook maybe?

Comment: Yes! that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm gonna check it out!